# Lazy Loading / Eager fetching in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, loading, lazy-evaluation

I have set the property **lazy="false"** in my hbm file for the column Contact in the table "Employee"

The below query is executed to retrieve the Employee with Id 5:

```
Select e from Employee e where e.id = 5
```

On execution, a number of queries are being executed and I guess it is due to non Lazy Loading.

How to make sure that only one query is executed? Can we change the query keeping the property lazy as false? If not, what should be the change in the query to retrieve the record?

I'm using **Spring+Hibernate**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your query, I'm going to assume you're using HQL for this.  I'm also going to assume `Contact` is a reference.

```
select e from Employee e left join fetch e.Contact where e.Id = 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes im using HQL and Contact is a reference. Here we should set **lazy="true"** yea?

Comment: Setting lazy to true or false won't change this query getting the `Contact` automatically.  You'll have to decide based on your requirements and performance if you want `Contact` to be default lazy and only eagerly load in this query or not.

Comment: so that means if I set lazy="false" and execute the above query, Contact will not be loaded? I thought setting lazy="false" will load the Contact always?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the original point.  I thought you were looking for a way to keep Contact lazy but load it eagerly sometimes.  Executing the above query will load Contact every time regardless of the lazy loading setting.  Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Mainly, **I want the number of queries reduced**, which as of now is very high. This i feel is because of the lazy="false" property. Will setting lazy = "true" and executing the above query do the trick?

Comment: Yea, it will change getting the employee from 2 queries to 1 query.  This query does the same as setting the `Contact` to eagerly loading with join fetch.  If you have multiple collection references you'll have to look out for `cross joins`, more info on that [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies?_sscc=t)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You mean if there are two references for which I need the child data? For Eg if I need the details of the column Organization which is a reference along with Contact?

Comment: No, if you have multiple collections.  Like if you have a list of `Contact` and also a list of `Address` for every `Employee`.  Then when you perform the query you may end up getting duplicate `Employee`.

Comment: you mean if I need to get the Address which is a column in Contact table?

Comment: No, if `Address` is a completely separate entity than `Contact`, and `Employee` has many of each of them.

Comment: One more doubt. What difference does setting fetch="join" and fetch="select" make?

Comment: Using `fetch="join"` uses sql `join` statements to select references.  Using `fetch="select"` sends one query for every reference.  That's why the hql statement I posted above is equivalent to using `fetch="join"`